# inserting few copies of the same page into PDF

Tags: command-line, pdf, pdftk

I want to insert X blank pages into PDF document.
I can do it with pdftk :

```
pdftk A=book.pdf B=page.pdf cat A1-end B output output.pdf
```

When I want insert more than one page, I can do something like that:

```
pdftk A=book.pdf B=page.pdf cat A1-end B B B output output.pdf
```

Is  there a syntax which allows to insert X pages without repeating the same parameter in command line?

Comment: in bash you could replace `B B B` with `$(printf "B %.0s" {1..3})'